# Creating a dataset for running a conditional logistic regression

Tags: r, regression, logistic

I plan on running a conditional logistic regression and I have the following dataset where 90 individuals (1:90) choose stores A, B and C. I do not have an outside option, such as not going to the store. But I do have a variable of `characteristics`, which makes it possible to run the analysis under the following condition: individual i, with characteristics j, chooses some store (e.g. "A"). So I match every individual with the same characteristic and place it as an approximate "control", but I also maintain every individual choice in the dataset -- and every individual i, with characteristics j, is used as "control" for individuals k (where k=/=i) and the characteristics are the same as individual i.

If were to run this in R, it would go as the following code:

```
#creating a dataset for running a conditional logistic regression

#matched version

df=data.frame(characteristic_match=rep(1:5,18),
              selection=c(rep("A",45),rep("B",36),
                          rep("C",9)),
              value=c(10*rnorm(45,10),
              1000*rnorm(36,5),
              2000*rnorm(9,5)),
              ID=1:90)
df

   characteristic_match selection       value ID
1                     1         A   101.66264  1
2                     2         A    99.62911  2
3                     3         A   117.25677  3
4                     4         A   107.06362  4
5                     5         A   100.94380  5
6                     1         A    95.32993  6
7                     2         A   110.29087  7
8                     3         A    95.10570  8
9                     4         A   101.39081  9
10                    5         A    93.10440 10
11                    1         A    88.23902 11
12                    2         A    72.08422 12
13                    3         A   100.27449 13
14                    4         A   121.69462 14
15                    5         A   108.00957 15
16                    1         A    96.21220 16
17                    2         A   109.91149 17
18                    3         A    98.92482 18
19                    4         A    92.02296 19
20                    5         A   103.92772 20
21                    1         A   117.95852 21
22                    2         A    89.68058 22
23                    3         A    93.32911 23
24                    4         A   114.51122 24
25                    5         A    96.06580 25
26                    1         A   102.84215 26
27                    2         A    78.06707 27
28                    3         A   115.77903 28
29                    4         A    95.72032 29
30                    5         A    92.91583 30
31                    1         A    96.13472 31
32                    2         A   106.38707 32
33                    3         A   118.43684 33
34                    4         A   109.48427 34
35                    5         A    85.48377 35
36                    1         A   104.43109 36
37                    2         A    99.45702 37
38                    3         A    80.42210 38
39                    4         A    90.38894 39
40                    5         A   103.85212 40
41                    1         A    96.92661 41
42                    2         A    92.65430 42
43                    3         A    95.38558 43
44                    4         A   100.68967 44
45                    5         A   112.58333 45
46                    1         B  4546.24869 46
47                    2         B  4318.22014 47
48                    3         B  2603.37593 48
49                    4         B  4491.54766 49
50                    5         B  5257.37517 50
51                    1         B  5096.96571 51
52                    2         B  3482.98104 52
53                    3         B  5073.48220 53
54                    4         B  4792.87771 54
55                    5         B  2540.90822 55
56                    1         B  4970.27492 56
57                    2         B  4619.81257 57
58                    3         B  4711.38638 58
59                    4         B  4254.47726 59
60                    5         B  6593.99583 60
61                    1         B  5419.07639 61
62                    2         B  4773.22751 62
63                    3         B  6753.05219 63
64                    4         B  4036.41123 64
65                    5         B  8100.93076 65
66                    1         B  3744.90732 66
67                    2         B  4874.38897 67
68                    3         B  3676.11969 68
69                    4         B  4434.53983 69
70                    5         B  5217.50811 70
71                    1         B  5670.52903 71
72                    2         B  4783.34079 72
73                    3         B  5143.90207 73
74                    4         B  5803.08883 74
75                    5         B  6867.56761 75
76                    1         B  3938.85208 76
77                    2         B  4943.64178 77
78                    3         B  3497.29088 78
79                    4         B  4967.55828 79
80                    5         B  5369.81543 80
81                    1         B  5877.69901 81
82                    2         C  8787.47615 82
83                    3         C 10990.99857 83
84                    4         C  8657.24290 84
85                    5         C  8159.47450 85
86                    1         C 10926.74186 86
87                    2         C  8694.59774 87
88                    3         C 11783.12132 88
89                    4         C  9895.20475 89
90                    5         C  8569.39552 90
```

And then, for every individual, a set of controls is "rowbinded" with following code:

```
require(dplyr)

df$dep_dum=0

for(i in 1:dim(df)[1]) {

  print(i)
  df_s = df[i,]
  df_s$dep_dum[1]=1
  c=df_s$characteristic_match[1]
  r=df_s$ID[1]
  s=df_s$selection[1]
  df_match=df %>% filter(characteristic_match==c) %>%
                  filter(ID!=r) %>%
                  filter(selection!=s)

  df_s = rbind(df_s,df_match)
  df_s$new_id=i

  if(i==1){

    df_m=df_s

    next
  }

  df_m = rbind(df_s, df_m)  

}

df_m = df_m %>% select(-ID)


head(df_m)

   characteristic_match selection      value dep_dum new_id
90                    5         C 8737.69734       1     90
1                     5         A  101.64083       0     90
2                     5         A   95.74073       0     90
3                     5         A  123.26963       0     90
4                     5         A   98.52406       0     90
5                     5         A  111.93650       0     90



survival::clogit(dep_dum ~ value + strata(new_id), data = df_m)
Call:
survival::clogit(dep_dum ~ value + strata(new_id), data = df_m)

            coef  exp(coef)   se(coef)      z      p
value -8.791e-05  9.999e-01  4.028e-05 -2.183 0.0291

Likelihood ratio test=5.24  on 1 df, p=0.02209
n= 1028, number of events= 90
```

I do not share all the new structure because it has 1028 observations. My question is: am I wrong to create the dataset as I did, what are the possible problems?